# Python - Glob - Reading in .csv data according to filename, and plotting data with color according to the filename

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I'm reading in multiple datalogger files, in .csv form, into Python.  My *objective* is as follows:

- To read in each file from my directory, and if the filename starts with a K, then graph it in one color ... and if the filename starts with a Z, to graph those datapoints in another color.
- So, effectively, I want to have a plot with only two colors on it.  One color from the files that started with "K", and another color from the files that started with "Z".

*Where I'm stuck:*

- In the code below, I'm only reading in the files from filenamesK.  However, I would like to incorporate filenamesZ into this loop and plot them on the same graph.
- It's been a few years since I've programmed in Python (not in a technical role anymore), and I understand that there's probably a more efficient way to do what I'm doing :) .

  ```
   import pandas as pd
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from glob import glob

   filenamesK = glob("C:/Users/K*.csv")
   filenamesZ = glob("C:/Users/Z*.csv")

   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   for f in filenamesK:
         df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',',skiprows=24)
         df.columns=['sample','Time','ms','Temperature',]
         df=df.astype(str)

         df["Temperature"] = df["Temperature"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)

         color = next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)['color']
         ax.plot(df[["Temperature"]], color=color)
   plt.show()
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (currently only) other answer seems straight forward, however, I would suggest creating a function for your plotting instead of nesting lots of `if` statements within a long `for`-loop.

Below is a simple function that takes the `filename` (from which to load the data), the `ax` to plot in and and the `color` you want the plot to have..

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob

filenamesK = glob("C:/Users/K*.csv")
filenamesZ = glob("C:/Users/Z*.csv")

def plot_data(filename, fig_ax, color):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',',skiprows=24)
    df.columns=['sample','Time','ms','Temperature',]
    df=df.astype(str)

    df["Temperature"] = df["Temperature"].str.replace('\+ ', '').str.replace(' ', '').astype(float)

    # no need for this:
    # color = next(fig_ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)['color']

    fig_ax.plot(df[["Temperature"]], color=color)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in filenamesK:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'blue')

for f in filenamesZ:
    plot_data(f, ax, 'red')

plt.show()
```

This could be further improved (in terms of readability) by extracting yet another function for reading the data. That is, one for reading data from a given file, and one for plotting them.

Comment: Hello @Wololo, this worked beautifully!  I really like the usage of the function. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @Gary. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the range `[]` for the starting character:

```
import glob

for name in glob.glob('[K,Z]*.csv'):
    if name.startswith('K'):
        color = 'r'
    elif name.startswith('K'):
        color = 'g'
    else:
        color = 'k'
    # the rest of the code <...>
```

However, it seems that `glob` can be case sensitive and insensitive [depending on the system](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/06/24/python_glob_case_sensitivity/).

So, maybe a better solution would be using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
import os
import re

regex = '?P<key>(K|Z).*\.scv'
for fname in os.listdir(path):
    search = re.search(regex, fname)
    if search:
        if search.group('key') == 'K':
            color = 'r'
        elif search.group('key') == 'Z':
            color = 'g'
        else:
            color = 'k'
    
# rest of the code <...>
```